# Are there established alternatives to ISomething / ISomethingable for interfaces?

Tags: naming-conventions, interface

The .NET standard of prefixing an interface name with an I seems to be becoming widespread and isn't just limited to .NET any more. I have come across a lot of Java code that uses this convention (so it wouldn't surprise me if Java used it before C# did). Also Flex uses it, and so on. The placing of an I at the start of the name smacks of Hungarian notation though and so I'm uncomfortable with using it.

So the question is, is there an alternative way of denoting that Something is an interface, rather than a class and is there any need to denote it like this anyway. Or is it a case its become a standard and so I should just accept it and stop trying to stir up "religious wars" by suggesting it be done differently?

Comment: It is actually considered BAD practice in java. See Effective Java by  Joshua Bloch. This is great, but also rather sad that c# still uses it.

Comment: @drozzy, (or anyone reading it) -- do you remember where J.Bloch discussed this topic (I mean page)? I have second edition of this book and I cannot find any reference to "I" naming convention.

Comment: @greenoldman Good point, he does not actually say it's "bad", just does not mention it. See p. 237-238 Effective Java 2nd. Sorry for my over-zealousness.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the Framework Design Guidelines book:

> Interfaces representing roots of a hierarchy (e.g. IList) should also use nouns or noun phrases. Interfaces representing capabilities should use adjectives and adjective phrases (e.g. IComparable, IFormattable).

Also, from the annotations on interface naming:

> KRZYSZTOF CWALINA: One of the few
> prefixes used is “I” for interfaces
> (as in ICollection), but that is for
> historical reasons. In retrospect, I
> think it would have been better to use
> regular type names. In a majority of
> the cases developers don’t care that
> something is an interface and not an
> abstract class, for example.
>
> BRAD ABRAMS: On the other hand, the “I” prefix on interfaces is a clear
> recognition of the influence of COM
> (and Java) on the .NET Framework. COM
> popularized, even institutionalized,
> the notation that interfaces begin
> with “I.” Although we discussed
> diverging from this historic pattern
> we decided to carry forward the
> pattern as so many of our users were
> already familiar with COM.
>
> JEFFREY RICHTER: Personally, I like the
> “I” prefix and I wish we had more
> stuff like this. Little one-character
> prefixes go a long way toward keeping
> code terse and yet descriptive. As I
> said earlier, I use prefixes for my
> private type fields because I find
> this very useful.
>
> BRENT RECTOR Note:
> this is really another application of
> Hungarian notation (though one without
> the disadvantages of the notation's
> use in variable names).

It has very much become a widely adopted standard, and while it is a form of Hungarian, as Brent states, it doesn't suffer from the disadvantages of using Hungarian notation in variable names.

Comment: Wow, those are some smart guys. I'm a big fan of Brad Abrams particularly.

Answer (score 16):

I would just accept it, to be honest. I know what you mean about being a bit like Hungarian notation (or at least abuse of the same) but I think it gives sufficient value to be worth doing in this case.

With dependency injection being in vogue, often I find I end up with an interface and a single production implementation. It's handy to make them easily distinguishable just with the I prefix.

One little data point: I work with both Java and C# a fair amount, and I regularly find myself having to check which types in Java are actually interfaces, particularly around the collection framework. .NET just makes this simple. Maybe it doesn't bother other people, but it bothers me.

+1 for IFoo from me.

Comment: I don't see why so many find it useful to distinguish interfaces from other types by means of type naming. A modern IDE will place a nice icon next to the file name. Besides, if you're not familiar with the type, chances are you're going to need to open it up and read the source/docs anyway.

Comment: @i3ensays: "Next to the filename" assumes you're looking at it in a package browser or whatever. I'd rather not have to take any action when just *reading the code*. Yes, I can look everything up, but I'd rather not. It's definitely a subjective thing, but I like the .NET convention for this.

Comment: this probably depends on your text editor / IDE, but in-code intellisense handles the distinctions for me quite well. For example, when I type "new" while declaring an assignment I can auto-complete the assignment with all known implementing types showing in a subcontext menu.

Comment: @i3ensays: That's when you're *writing* code. I spend more time *reading* code than writing it... and a lot of that time is in diff views etc rather than IDEs.

Answer (score 10):

As a .NET programmer (for the most part), I actually prefer the Java convention of dropping the `I` here, for a simple reason: Often, small redesigns require the change from an interface into an abstract base class or vice versa. If you have to change the name, this might require a lot of unnecessary refactoring.

On the other hand, usage for the client should be transparent so they shouldn't care for this type hint. Furthermore, the “able” suffix in `Thingable” should be enough of a hint. It works well enough in Java.

/EDIT: I'd like to point out that the above reasoning had prompted me to drop the `I` prefix for private projects. However, upon checking one of them against the FxCop rule set, I promptly reverted to the usage of `I`. Consistency wins here, *even though [a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds](http://www.bartleby.com/100/420.47.html)*.

Comment: That sucks... when consistency starts to dictate programming practice, it is a slippery slope.

Comment: @drozzy: Consistency *always* dictates programming practice. And the “slippery slope” argument is a logical fallacy. In fact, if you want to design a reusable API for a programming language you are catering to expectations. The API should be easy to use and this means that it should be consistent with what the user already knows. There *are* reasons to violate this rule but a stupid `I` in front of the class name is not one of them. I think Microsoft’s naming convention is stupid but the train has left the station.

Comment: Consistency within an API is more to my liking. When you want to be consistent with other API's then I agree, you have to conform. But if you are working on a project independently, and consistently drop the I-prefix, why not? In fact, why not teach NEW programmers to drop it...

Comment: @drozzy: well, **every** .NET project uses the .NET framework API. And that uses `I` as interface prefix. Furthermore, no real project is completely independent from the rest, sooner or later the project may grow so large that it needs to interact with other existing APIs. And every code should be written future proof since you never know if this code will in the future be used elsewhere or will need to interact with foreign code. The .NET framework basically dictates all the basic conventions to use in other .NET projects.

Comment: I do wander, what will happen if microsoft guys decide not to use it in the .net 5.0.

Comment: Well, in java it is easier - since it specifically distinguishes between pure interfaces (implements) and abstract classes (extends). Which makes INotation useless imho. .NET does not - so while in java we have "Adapter implements Observable extends BaseAdapter" in .NET it would be confusing "Adapter:Observable,BaseAdapter".

Comment: Although C# can use similar syntax for implementing interfaces and inheriting classes, they are semantically different concepts and, consequently, have different rules.  Often it will be necessary to have a closely-associated interface and class (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>` and `Enumerable<T>`).  If interface names didn't have the "I" prefix, so what is now `IEnumerable<T>` was instead `Enumerable<T>`, where should one expect to find what is now called `Enumerable<T>.Empty`?  BTW, I wonder why the "I" is uppercase?  Hatred of Apple?  `iMutableFnord` seems clearer than `IMutableFnord`.

Comment: @supercat `Enumerable` isn’t an abstract base class, it’s something completely different. And there isn’t really a problem of name clash. If you insist on using the same name (but why?) then you can always put the class in a different namespace. And the `I` is uppercase to be consistent with the [PascalCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_case#Variations_and_synonyms) naming convention. This isn’t Java, after all, so there is no reason to make the `I` lowercase.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: `Enumerable` isn't an abstract base class, but static members like `Empty` can't be part of an interface; if the interface were called `Enumerable`, what would be the "obvious" name for a closely-associated static class?  As for PascalCase/camelCase naming, I would think prefixes should be regarded as different from "words".

Comment: @supercat What about `EnumerableHelpers`, `EnumerableExtensions` or `EnumerableMixin`? That’s what it is, after all.

Comment: @drozzy: The fact that C# uses the same notation for class inheritance versus interface implementation is a C# thing, not a .NET thing; in the .NET framework they are handled differently, and not all languages follow C# leads (I know that VB.NET uses different keywords for `Inherits` and `Implements`).  Of much greater importance are some *consumer-side* semantic differences between abstract classes and interfaces which exist in .NET but are not relevant in Java.  A generic type constrained to an abstract class will always be a reference type, but one constrained to an interface may not.

Comment: Since all non-primitive types in Java are reference types, such distinctions don't matter on that language/platform, but on a platform like .NET which includes non-primitive value types they can be very important.

Answer (score 1):

Its all about **style** and **readability**. Prefixing Interfaces with "I" is merely a naming convention and style guideline that has caught on. The compilers themselves couldn't care less.

Comment: That's really true about Hungarian notation in general. It is simply a naming convention for humans reading the code. The compilers don't care what the variables are named as long as they are uniequely named and use only valid symbols.

Answer (score 1):

My main assumption is that the most important thing is to maintain readability in domain part of the implementation. Therefore:

- If you have one behaviour and one possible implementation, then just don't create an interface:

  `public class StackOverflowAnswerGenerator { }`
- If you have one behaviour and many possible implementations, then there is no problem and you can just drop the "I", and have:

  `public interface StackOverflowAnswerGenerator {}`

  `public class StupidStackOverflowAnswerGenerator : StackOverflowAnswerGenerator {}`

  `public class RandomStackOverflowAnswerGenerator : StackOverflowAnswerGenerator {}`

  `public class GoogleSearchStackoverflowAnswerGenerator : StackOverflowAnswerGenerator {}`

  `//...`
- The real problem comes when you have one behaviour and one possible implementation but you need an interface to describe its behaviour (for example for convenient testing, because of convention in your project, using some library/framework which enforces this, ...). Possible solutions, other from prefixing the interface are:

  **a)** Prefix or suffix the implementation (as stated in some other answers in this topic)

  **b)** Use a different namespace for interface:

  ```
  namespace StackOverflowAnswerMachine.Interfaces 
  {
    public interface StackOverflowAnswerGenerator {}
  }

  namespace StackOverflowAnswerMachine 
  { 
    public class StackOverflowAnswerGenerator : Interfaces.StackOverflowAnswerGenerator
  {}

  }
  ```

  **c)** Use a different namespace for implementation:

  ```
  namespace StackOverflowAnswerMachine 
  {
    public interface StackOverflowAnswerGenerator {}
  }

  namespace StackOverflowAnswerMachine.Implementations 
  { 
    public class StackOverflowAnswerGenerator : StackOverflowAnswerMachine.StackOverflowAnswerGenerator 
  {}

  }
  ```

Even though I think the last possibility is the cleanest, its one drawback is that even though `using StackOverflowAnswerMachine;` gives you access to all domain objects you must prefix all domain interfaces not to be confused with their implementations. That may feel like something not very convenient but in clean design usually a class doesn't use many other domain objects, and mostly you need to use the prefix only in field declaration and constructor parameter list. So, that is my current recommendation.

The client of domain functionality shouldn't need to know whether they're using an interface, an abstract class or a concrete class. If they need to know this, then there is some serious problem in such a project, because it has domain logic and infrastructural concerns mixed on the same abstraction layer. Therefore I recommend "**a**" or "**c**" solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The coding standard for Symbian has interfaces (pure abstract C++ classes) denoted with an M rather than an I.

Otherwise, the only other way I have seen of denoting interfaces is through context.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET, Microsoft's Framework Design Guidelines book absolutely recommends it, and yes, it is very much standard. I have never seen it done otherwise, and to create a new convention would only serve to confuse people.

I should add that I dislike Hungarian notation too, but this and the case of prefixing class variables with an underscore are good exceptions to me, because they make code so much more readable.

Comment: class variables prefixed with _ annoy me in C++. _ is meant to denote system variables and libraries, not class variables.

Comment: For C++, I agree with you. I like them specifically for C#.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought this naming convention is a bit of a dinosaur. Nowadays IDEs are powerful enough to tell us that something is an interface. Adding that I makes the code harder to read so if you really want to have a naming convention that separates interfaces from classes I would append Impl to the name of the implementing class.

```
public class CustomerImpl implements Customer
```

Comment: But how do we know Customer is an interface and not, say, an abstract class?

Comment: I think the "Impl" suffix makes the code harder to read than an "I" prefix on an interface, especially for public facing APIs.

Comment: @RobertS. why do you care? seriously.

Comment: @ScottDorman some might mention sort order listings within a package (the implementation will likely fall just after the interface), but I agree, the suffix is nasty and would rather see implementation detail added to the prefix name (e.g. PremiumCustomer)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for an alternative, so here is one I have encountered:

Use **no** prefix on the interface class, but use a **c** or **C** prefix on the corresponding concrete classes.  Most of your code will generally reference the interface, so why pollute it with the prefix and not the generally much less used concrete type.

This approach does introduce one inconsistency in that some concrete types will be prefixed (the ones with matching interfaces) and others will not.  This may be useful since it reminds developers that an interface exists and its use should be preferred over the concrete type.

To be honest, *I* use the prefix on the interface, but I think it is more because I have become so accustomed and comfortable with to it.