# Why prefix C# interface names with an “I”

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, interface

What is the rationale behind this naming convention?

I don't see any benefit. The extra prefix just pollutes the API.

My thinking is inline with Konrad's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222502/9898) to this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222457); the chosen [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222500/9898T) of which is mostly what I am asking for here.

Comment: I see two votes to close---but I'm not convinced it's really an exactly duplicate of the request for alternatives.  If somebody will convince me, I'll vote to close. (Please leave a comment.)

Comment: Not duplicated and actually a good question.

Comment: Not a duplicate, yet Jon Limjap seems to think otherwise. What can I do?

Comment: It wasn't just Jon Limjap.  3 people have to vote for it, he just happened to be the 3rd person to do so.

Comment: @Simucal - Thanks for the clarification. Is it possible to vote to unclose it? Would be helpful if a link the the supposed duplicate was made available by the voters.

Comment: Yes, users can vote to reopen.  It takes 3 users to vote to reopen a question.  Currently one user has voted to do so, so it needs two more.

Comment: You also have to have a certain rep level to do so, that level should be in the FAQ (3k rep)

Answer (score 56):

Its the complete opposite, the naming convention clearly identifies an interface.

For example if you have:

```
public class Dog : IPet, IMammal
{
    ....
```

Just from reading it, I can safely assume that IPet and IMammal are probably interfaces.

The .NET CLR allows for single class inheritance.  So, if I have a base class..I can only inherit one class from it.  Lets change the IPet interface to a base class..our example now becomes

```
public class Dog : Pet, IMammal
{
    ....
```

I am inheriting from the Pet class and implementing the IMammal interface.

If we did it what you are suggesting and removed the letter "I" we have this:

```
public class Dog : Pet, Mammal
{
    ....
```

Which one is the class I am inheriting from?  Which is the interface I am implementing?  It gets confusing right? (FYI..you are supposed to put the base class always first, so you could argue that point...but if you are arguing to remove the letter I from prefixing interface names I doubt you follow that practice as well)

As you can see that naming convention easily tells me a lot about my object without me having to investigate further.  I can easily see what I am inheriting vs what I am implementing.

Comment: It makes sense. So, in C# , Java's "extends and implements" are mixed together?

Comment: I follow the "base class always first" convention you mention. Nonetheless, I can't agree with your claim "naming convention easily tells me a lot about my object". Case in point, distinguishing between interface, abstract/concrete class, enum, struts, etc. isn't meaningful to me at the API level.

Comment: Why don't we prefix abstract/concrete types with "A"/"C", enumerations with "E", structures with "S", etc.?

Comment: I use a programming "environment" that is SO awful, that methods, attributes, and objects, must be prefixed with "met, attr and obj" repectively. objEmployee.metUpdate( objOther.attrId ). This is extremely readable and very clear, but I just hate it!!!

Comment: @Oscar - I can't tell if you're being sarcastic or idiotic. Either way I don't think any sane programmer would vote for those uses.

Comment: it doesn't sound like it's his choice

Comment: This is the best answer, but the actual reasons are (according to Krzysztof Cwalina) that "I" is used for `historical reasons` and (according to Brad Abrams) that it is a `clear recognition of the influence of COM (and Java) on the .NET Framework` and the decision to carry it forward was because so many early adopters of the .NET Framework `were already familiar with COM`. (See this answer for the more detailed quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222457/are-there-established-alternatives-to-isomething-isomethingable-for-interfaces/222500#222500)

Comment: I personally like that all interfaces are prefixed with an 'I'.  It allows me to immediately recognize an interface quickly.

Comment: It is rather ironic, that java actually got it right. No longer are the interfaces prefixed with an "I", but it is actually considered BAD practice. See "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch.

Comment: "Base class first" isn't just a convention.  It's required by the compiler: `Base class 'xyz' must come before any interfaces`.  This should not be taken to mean that I oppose using "I" as a prefix.  Among other things, it's nice to have a visual indicator of how interface-y my code is or isn't.

Comment: @Kyralessa visual "indicators" are one thing that text editors / IDEs do quite well (e.g. font coloring, icons, etc.)

Comment: What this doesn't address is the more fundamental question as to why do you need to identify a type as being an interface, any more than you need to identify whether it is a class or a struct... or whether it is Abstract or not..., or whether it contains instance members or only static ones...  I think we do, but I'm not sure as to what the best answer is as to why ....

Answer (score 31):

I also like it cause I can read it as "I verb-behavior" as in "ICanSave" or "IDoDoubleEntry"  etc...

Comment: Perhaps the prefix should be 'Me'.

Comment: yeah it could be argued that the "Am" is implied.. 
"IAmEnumerable" would arguably be clearer, albiet longer.

Comment: I always find my interface names sound a bit like lolcats. "ICanHasCheeseburger"

Comment: Doesn't this actually go against C#'s naming conventions? `ICanSave` should be `ISaveble`.

Comment: @Vapid, I guess it might be, in a very minor way, as a verb phrase is not, of course, an adjective, but the meaning is identical.  `ISaveble` or `I[Am]Saveble`  means the same thing as `ICanSave`. In fact, to my way of thinking about interfaces, it is closer to the real meaning. Interfaces are ways to declare to the compiler that a type, (class or struct), *implements some specific set of behaviors*, i.e., it forces the compiler to require that the type implements the behavior defined in the interface.  so, to me, a verb phrase, declaring that the type *does* something, is more appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesBretana I was just thinking because .NET names their interfaces as `IClonable`, `IDisposable`, and `IComparable` and not `ICanClone`, `ICanDispose` or, `ICanCompare`.

Comment: @Vapid,  Yes, you are correct. The "standard" naming conventions say that interface names should be nouns, noun phrases, or (as a secondary option), an adjective. It does not mention verbs or verb phrases.  I just think the verb phrase construction more clearly expresses the concept of "implementing an set of behavior".

Answer (score 26):

I think that the IInterface naming convention is silly. It's an example of Hungarian notation, and I subscribe to the school of thought that despises Hungarian notation. If you have an interface with only one implementation that has the same name, consider the possibility that this is a code smell.

However, I still use it, because in this case IInterface is recommended by Microsoft, and "standard is better than better".

Comment: I was never a fan of hungarian either, but I came across this old Joel article recently, which explains its origin and how it has been widely misunderstood - at least I can see the reason behind it now!
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 17):

Why isn't this a function of syntactical highlighting instead of Hungarian notation?  Why doesn't the IDE just italicize identifiers that refer to interfaces if it's so important to distinguish between classes and interfaces.  I hate putting "*" or "m*" before fields, "C" before classes, etc.  Even worse, it encourages programmers write really bad APIs such as:

```
public class List : IList
```

instead of a more reasonable:

```
public class LinkedList : List
public class ArrayList : List
public class HashList : List
```

Even the .NET common class authors fell into this trap.  A class name should NEVER be the name of the interface with just the "I" removed.  The class name should always tell the user how the class differs from other possible implementations of the interface(s).  I vote for dropping the stupid "I" for that reason alone.

Also, when I use intellisense, I want to group things by functional area, not whether it's a class or interface.  I never think, "I need an interface, not a class."  I always think, "I need something that does X".

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who sees it this way. It sure seems like I'm in the minority. 4 years later I'm still amazed at how many readers swear "its makes it easy to identify an interface" and completely miss the point.

Comment: This is a really good point when designing an interface with extensibility in mind, but another use case of abstracting interfaces (C# and Java) is purely for the benefit of decoupling to allow mocking of dependencies, where no other concrete implementation of the interface has been explicitly 'designed for'. So `MyReallySpecificBusinessComponent` and `IMyReallySpecificBusinessComponent` would be Ok. But definitely not `List`.

Answer (score 11):

Actually I find it useful to avoid naming clashes, I might for example create a concrete class called Fred that implements IFred

Comment: Naming clashes are avoided by using meaningful/useful names. E.g. Fred extends Person, implements Living, Breathing and other capabilities. Without more context I can't say for sure, but if Fred is a domain/model object, having an interface for it is probably superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

I always thought it was fun to use verbs for behavioral interfaces.  This is a departure from the class naming convention of using nouns, but it allows the class to "speak" to its behavior.

```
class Dog: IBark
```

This does not work well for structural interfaces like WCF interfaces, but we don't need to have fun all the time.

to answer your question, think of the `I` as "implements" So...

```
class DogDataService : Dog, IDataService
```

this service class inherits from `Dog` and implements `IDataService`

I'm still not really answering your question, but the `I` is useful because you get naming collisions between namespace, class and interface.

```
namespace DataService
interface DataService
class DataService: DataService
```

so we end up with

```
namespace DataServices
interface IDataService
class DataService : IDataService
```

I think in reality, it's a sanity convention.

Comment: +1 - generally speaking I think naming conventions indicate a weakness in the development language (and that is probably the case here), but it is nonetheless important to be able to avoid those collisions when you want to use dependency injection and to mock collaborator objects. There's really no alternative to a naming convention when you're creating interfaces for domain objects.

Comment: /shrug I use it for WCF services too. I have IServeData and ICanMakePayments for my two services.

Comment: @JeffSternal I think you might be applying the "every object must have an interface" anti-pattern. You probably should not create interfaces for domain objects; they are often an expected part of your public API.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider the two "best-practice-aphorisms"

*clarity is king*

and

*noise is bad*

there is a conflict between these. The question is: when does clarity become noise?

For me it more noisy (but equally clear) to write `Person person = new PersonImpl()` than `IPerson person = new Person()`.

Comment: Or better yet, Person p = new TallPerson(); but in my case, Person is not likely to be an interface. Instead it is a base type which TallPerson extends, that or an abstract type. In either case the "interface" of Person is implied by its public API. I despise FooImpl() as much as IFoo.

Answer (score 3):

It's either that or add "Impl" to the implementation of the interface (argh). I don't have a problem with the "I", it is the simplest and most straightforward naming for an interface.

Comment: I disagree with the "Impl" suggestion - it would be wasted noise just as the "I" prefix is. An implementation should be named with its implementation in mind. For example, an interface "Database" might be implemented with "RelationalDatabase" and "InMemoryDatabase".

Comment: It's a convention, you are not required to follow it if you don't like it.

Comment: Not a matter of me liking it. I'm questioning its value. I like to adhere to conventions not solely for the sake of following the pack. I want to understand the rational. Hopefully, someone can articulate that rational beyond "it lets you know its an interface" (which the IDE does w/ pretty icons).

Answer (score 3):

The "I" convention seems to be an old convention that wouldn't be relevant today. Current code editor provides lots of insight about the type you are using, so arguing that It's easier to identify the interface is like asking for a namespace to be prefixed by a "N" because you want to be sure that you will not confound it with a concrete class (prefix with a "C"?).

A convention doesn't mean that It's a good convention. Sometimes, It's just because people get to use it...

Take for example the C# documentation generator: It doesn't care about it... if your interface is not prefixed with a "I" you will still see your interface in the interface part of your documentation. Do you really think that having a prefix "I" for all your interfaces inside the interface section of your documentation is a relevant information and help you to better identify interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

The need to differentiate between an interface and a class actually indicates a design flaw. In a well designed application, it will always be clear. A subclass should always be a specialization and classes can only be specialized in one subject, never more.

A class should have a single reason for existence. It should never be required to put secondary roles in a base class. E.g.:

```
public class XmlConfigurationFile : ConfigurationFile, IDisposable
{
}

public class YamlConfigurationFile : ConfigurationFile, IDisposable
{
}
```

The first one is a configuration file that is specialized in Xml, the second one is specialized in Yaml. These are also disposable, but that doesn't matter as much. You didn't create these two classes because of a different disposing processes.

Constrast this with:

```
public class XmlConfigurationFile : IDisposable, ConfigurationFile
{
}
```

This will tell you that the main purpose a XmlConfigurationFile has, is that it is disposable. That you can use it as a way to represent configuration files is nice, but is secondary.

The problem starts when you create classes that have multiple reasons for existence:

```
public class MyConfigurationFile : XmlConfigurationFile, YamlConfigurationFile
{
}
```

Even if XmlConfigurationFile and YamlConfigurationFile would have been interfaces, it still indicates bad design. How can your configuration file be Xml and Yaml at the same time?

If you read through the examples given (here and elsewhere), people always struggle to find a good example of when the I-prefix matters. One of the answers here is:

```
public class Dog : Pet, Mammal
{
}
```

This is how this class will look like in an application about pets. A dog's main purpose is being a specialized pet, that can do pet-related things, not that it is a mammal.

```
public class Dog : Mammal, Pet
{
}
```

This is how the same class will look like in an application about animal classifications. It is nice to know a dog is a pet, but it's main purpose is being a specialized mammal, that can do mammal-related things.

I think your classes should tell you the correct story about the architecture and domain of your application. Requiring an interface to be prefixed with an 'I' is a technical requirement and doesn't help you to tell your application's story better.

Once you start writing small, dedicated, single-purpose classes, the need for knowing if it implements or extends will automatically vanish.

Comment: This needs to be the approved answer. Well written and informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It makes it easily identifiable as an interface.

Comment: I don't see any direct value in distinguishing between interfaces and implementations. Further elaboration might help.

Comment: To me, at lease, Implementation means a class, which should be defined according to logical entity/ object semantics, whereas Interface means behavior, or contract, which should be organized according to logical groupings of connected behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR - Extracting `interface IFoo` from `class Foo` is common in SOLID decoupling, especially for Unit Testing purposes**

To me the dual convention of class `Foo` implementing interface `IFoo` (especially if both are in the same assembly) conveys a specific intention that:

- Coupling on a dependency to a `Foo` should always be indirect, through the corresponding `IFoo` interface (and likely to be injected via an IoC container)
- The initial design of `IFoo` is a proprietary, non-reusable interface specifically to allow classes dependent on `Foo` to mock out this dependency during unit testing.
- Beyond the above, a reader doesn't need to infer any additional intelligence in the design of the `IFoo` interface
- Conversely, if multiple concrete implementation classes of `IFoo` are required at a later point, that proper interface segregation design will need to be retrofitted into the hierarchy.

**Rationale**

In order to be able to Mock or Stub out a class, a widely accepted best practice in Unit Testing is to decouple dependencies between classes only via interfaces. This interface decoupling will also be done to classes which would otherwise [never had a design requirement for polymorphicism](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it) (i.e. only one such implementation would have existed, were it not for the need for unit testing).

As a consequence, the refactoring and reuse of these interfaces (e.g. the [Interface Segregation Principal of `SOLID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)) isn't frequently applied to such 'mockable' interfaces - there is often a 1:1 correlation between the public methods, properties and events of a 'mockable' class (`Foo`) and its decoupled interface `IFoo` (similar to the COM-era [automatic interfaces in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973861.aspx#interinher_topic6)).

Tools such as [VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx) and Resharper can make extracting such public symbols from a class into a separate interface trivial, as an afterthought.

Further, if we consider that Mocking frameworks like Moq allow [definition of implementations of the interface on-the-fly](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods), we need not waste effort naming the concrete test double implementation class.

Answer (score 1):

Naming conventions offer the benefit of telling you something about the object before you use it.  Naming conventions have been widely used for many years, going all the way back to fortran's insistence that integer values were restricted (if I remember correctly) to variable names like "i" and "j".

Hungariation notation took naming conventions to a whole new ugly level tha described the variable type, whether or not it was a pointer, etc.  Many of us who were exposed to lots of code with Hungarian notation developed nervous twitches and verbal stutters.

Prefixing interface names with I is a relatively low-impact, harmless way of identifying that object.

Comment: How does identifying a type is an interface benefit the API? (I do understand the difference between interfaces and classes).

Answer (score 0):

It is just a naming convention so everybody would know if it is an interface or something else it is not mandatory nor by the compiler nor by the IDE but All the interfaces i saw in my entire life starts with the letter I

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I believe prefixing with I then description is wrong because it means implementations can have a shorter name. IList (intf) -> List. This is an anti-pattern as we all know we should be using intf and probably only concrete types when creating. Don't flame me this is a generalization but the premise is intf only impl rarely. The implementation name should describe how it's implementing the intf or what it's doing. Think intf List, LinkedList which implements List using a linked list. Who cares if it's longer as we should be using List most of the time. If we have a class implementing many intf we probably should not include all the intf as the shadows the real purpose of the class. IN the case something removed without the intf makes sense. Eg ppl call me by name not Person, Sibling, developer etc using my name is the best most descriptive name. I suppose if a class is impl a simple intf then call it Default Intf which makes it on ious this is the default implementation of Intf. 
Names of classes sHould in the end be human readable and almost a short phrase describing their purpose. Prefix codes etc are not great as we communicate with words not codes. Computers do t cAre what classes are called so why remains is that we name things so the names help us and our colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to traditional convention from Hungarian Notation.
[Interface Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says "Prefix interface names with the letter I, to indicate that the type is an interface."
[Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx) also says "DO prefix interface names with the letter I, to indicate that the type is an interface."

It is just a coding convention, So it's to hard to determine good or bad.
Important things is consistency.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely its to make it easily identifiable in intellisense, since all the interfaces will clump together.  Similar to how I prefix all my UI controls with btn, tb, lb.  When intellisense kicks in everything is clumped together in one easy group.

Comment: I believe the IDE can "clump" without use of naming conventions.

Answer (score -1):

With all of the arguments about naming conventions and giving proper names to variables and methods that actually describe what they do...why not just name your interfaces (e.g. PetInterface, PlayerInterface, etc.) and do away with the prefix "I" all together. So what you have to type an additional 9 letters, at least the "I" is removed and we know it is not a class, because it says "Interface".

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Why not name your classes "DogClass"? If someone did this in my code-base, I would be very upset. There is a standard; use it.